# При вводе текста в TextView не отображаются изменения

Tags: android, input, textview

Есть в приложении View, который строится на основании xml и css - дерево, и если дернуть метод representation для верхнего элемента дерева, то оно само отрисует себя по узлам и листамб каждый из которых представляет ViewGroup или View соответственно. Для тегов label в разметке строится TextView, для ImageButton строятся ImageView, для контейнеров, как правило RelativeLayout. ПРоблема с TextView, это поле может быть редактируемым. EditText я не рассматривал, так как поле должно выглядеть как простейший текст, а EditText из за особенностей своей разметки просто режется на финальной отрисоке шаблона из-за того, что его height почти вдвое больше высоты его текста. Когда я создаю View на основе элемента представляющего текст, я делаю следующее

```
@Override
public View representation(Context context, CssStyleSheet cssStyleSheet, Template.Manifest manifest) {
    label = new Text(context);
    label.setHint(defaultText);
    cssStyleSheet.applyStyle(label, id, cssClass);
    if (editable) {
        label.setFocusable(true);
        label.setCursorVisible(true);
        label.setClickable(true);
        label.setEnabled(true);
        label.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        label.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                label.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                label.requestFocus();
        });

        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else {
        label.setFocusable(false);
        label.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // user touches widget on phone with touch screen
        label.setClickable(false);
    }
    return label;
}
```

то есть обеспечиваю TextView все необходимые параметры для использования его в качестве поля ввода. Однако при вводе текста я вижу изменение только в начале ввода, то есть если я ввожу туда "fgdlhfgld" я вижу в TextView только "f"или максимум "fg", после чего никаких изменений не происходит, чего бы я не вводил. Если я переоткрываю фрагмент, на котором у меня находится эта view, то view перересовывается (не перерендеривается, именно переотрисовывается, так как representation вызывается только если глобальный View == null), и я вижу все изменения, внесенные в текст, но если я снова нажму на это поле на устройстве и буду вводить текст, то я не увижу внешних изменений пока не переоткрою фрагмент с View.

Есть ли какой нибудь параметр для TextView который будет обновляеть его в  процессе ввода текста? Я пытался добавить OnKeyListener, где делал

```
label.setText(label.getText())
```

что не привело к результату и добавлял TextWatcher в котором пытался засетить приходящую строку в label, но получилась рекурсия, так как методы TextWatcher'a вызываются внутри setText.

Comment: использовать TextView , как Edittext - костыль. Высота у EditText задается фоном (background). Если вы выставите пустой background у Edittext, то его высота будет такой же, как у TextView

Comment: @metalurgus ммм, то есть вместо transparent сделать null?

Comment: @metalurgus может я что то не так делаю, но передавал и null в setBackground и 0 в setbackgroundcolor - высота остается прежней (с учетом underline)

Comment: @metalurgus Спасло создание et не из контекста, а из разметки, вот только тоже не вижу изменений при вводе текста 0_о